# SELECT INTO inserts only the last row - VBA, Access 2000?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this SQL string which I create in a Loop:

```
"SELECT '" & Trim(Str(j)) & "' AS cpa, Count(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("tipprod") & "')) AS BrojProd, Sum(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("povrsina") & "')) AS p, Sum(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("pmagacin") & "')) AS pm INTO T14_KPD_CPA_samo_podatoci FROM CPA_nezbirni WHERE (t4k" & Trim(Str(j)) & "<>'' Or t4k" & Trim(Str(j)) & " Is Not Null);"
```

And the loop I use is:

```
Dim j As Integer
j = 1
Do While j <= 3
    cpaSelectSQL = "SELECT '" & Trim(Str(j)) & "' AS cpa, Count(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("tipprod") & "')) AS BrojProd, Sum(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("povrsina") & "')) AS p, Sum(Val('" & rsCPANezbirni("pmagacin") & "')) AS pm INTO T14_KPD_CPA_samo_podatoci FROM CPA_nezbirni WHERE (t4k" & Trim(Str(j)) & "<>'' Or t4k" & Trim(Str(j)) & " Is Not Null);"
    Debug.Print "j = " & Str(j) & ", cpa select SQL: " & cpaSelectSQL
    DoCmd.RunSQL cpaSelectSQL, True

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

The problem I have, only the last generated row gets copied in T14_KPD_CPA_samo_podatoci i.e cpa = 3

I want to copy each for for the value of cpa 1 to 3.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: SELECT INTO will create the table if possible, you need an INSERT INTO once the table exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT INTO` is a "Create table" query, it will overwrite the target table each time you run it.

Once the table exists you need `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: I was first you know :)

Comment: I know. :) But *"Avoid answering questions in comments."*

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used this sort of SQL query

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, ..., coln) SELECT col1, col2,..., coln FROM table2 WHERE condition GROUP BY colx;
```